# Mathematica: Derivative appears to be wrong

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm first getting `f(x)` by computing an implicit equation. Then I want to take the derivative. Later on, when I plot both `f(x)` and `f'(x)`, they do not appear to correspond: the derivative is always negative. What am I doing wrong?

```
ClearAll[r, p, lambda, a, A, c, eta, f, y, constant1, constant2, eta, \
etaOfR]

eta[lambda_, f_] := 
  1 - constant2[lambda] + 
   constant1[lambda]*(Exp[lambda*(1 - f)] - 1 - lambda*(1 - f)) ;
etaOfR[lambda_] := Limit[eta[lambda, f], f -> 1];
constant1[lambda_] := Exp[-lambda]/(1 - Exp[-lambda]);
constant2[lambda_] := constant1[lambda]*(Exp[lambda] - 1 - lambda);
prof[p_] := (p - c)/p;
f[p_] := f /. 
    Solve[eta[lambda, f]*prof[p] == etaOfR[lambda]*prof[r], f] // 
   First // FullSimplify
{r, c, lambda} = List[4, 0.1, 0.01];
fDeriv[p_] = f'[p] // FullSimplify;
Plot[f[p], {p, 0.1, r}]
Plot[fDeriv[p], {p, 0.1, r}]
```

Here's the two plots: first `f`, then `f'`:

[image: f]
[image: f']

It looks the same when I first compute the derivative and then define `{r, c, lambda}`. I already swapped the order thinking that the unknowns were causing trouble, but the underlying issue appears to be something else.

Comment: It looks to me that your `fDeriv` is using the wrong branch of the Lambert function. Try replacing all instances of `ProductLog[x]` with `ProductLog[-1, x]`.

Comment: @J.M. is there any clean way of doing that, i.e. not explicitely rewriting `f()`? I tried `f[p_] := f ... , f, Reals]`, but that keeps on going.

Comment: That should be `fManuallyWritten'[p]`, no?

Comment: @J.M. ha - yes, that gives me the correct derivative. Coming back to my previous question - is there a way to enforce this behavior cleanly, without copy-pasting the intermediate result?

Comment: You might consider using `Reduce[]` to help you with how to restrict the domain properly. Ponder the difference between `Reduce[x == y Exp[y], y]` and `Reduce[{x == y Exp[y], y < -1}, y]`, for instance.

Comment: Define `ff[p_]=f[p]` (no `SetDelayed`). Then define the derivative in terms of `ff[p]` and the results will be consistent.